# Displaying progress bar upto response occur using jquery ajax submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am send request to PHP page by using jquery ajax concept, I have to display the response in dialog box. It works fine but the problem is it takes time to get response. So can I add progress bar to it.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "push/push_notify.php",
            data: "pushmessage="+message+"&iphone="+iphone+"&android="+android+"&blackberry="+blackberry,
            success: function(e){
                var response = e;
                apprise(response, {'animate':true});
            }
        });
       return false;
```

Comment: You can't really show a progress bar since there's no way to predict how long this operation will take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could show some spinner image before running the request and hide it after the request finishes, i the `complete` handler. For example:

```
$('#spinner').show();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "push/push_notify.php",
    complete: function() {
        $('#spinner').hide();
    },
    data: { 
        pushmessage: message, 
        iphone: iphone, 
        android: android, 
        blackberry: blackberry
    },
    success: function(e) {
        var response = e;
        apprise(response, {'animate':true});
    }
});
```

And here's a site for [some AJAX spinners](http://www.ajaxload.info/).